# warning from Eclipse

Tags: c

can somebody please explain what does it mean :
`passing arg 1 of 'free' discards qualifiers from pointer target type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "discards qualifies" pertains to `const` or `volatile`.  So you're probably passing a const pointer as a non-const argument.

You code probably resembles the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    const double *x ;
    x = (double *) malloc(4 * sizeof(double)) ;
    free(x) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

I borrowed this example from a [similar question asked on an online forum](http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/comp-lang-c/299780-free-consted-memory-without-warning.html).

The problem is that since you've said the data you're point to is `const`, you can't change it.  You can't initialize it, you can't modify it, you can't `free` it.  So don't use a `const` pointer as your only pointer to the result of a `malloc`.

Comment: yes, You are right, I'm passing it to free, why do I receive warning, what can I do with this?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `const` on a pointer you're using with `malloc` and `free`.  For what it's worth, I found a discussion on this topic: http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/comp-lang-c/299780-free-consted-memory-without-warning.html